# display fetched values in view

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. Please help me to solve this problem. I have fetched a data from my DB. I have to display these values in my view. I can get data in the view. But the detail-view shows "NOT SET". I have attached my view here. Thanks in advance.

**My controller action:**

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
            $host_id=$id;
            $model=new NimsoftHostsDetails;
            $detail = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_id'=>$id));
            $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$model,'host_detail'=>$detail
        ));

    }
```

**My View:**

```
<?php
/* @var $this NimsoftHostsDetailsController */
/* @var $model NimsoftHostsDetails */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Nimsoft Hosts Details'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Update NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('label'=>'Delete NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('label'=>'Manage NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>View NimsoftHostsDetails </h1>
<?php print_r($host_detail);?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
                'id',
        'host_id',
                'host_start_date',
        'host_end_date',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDetailView shows details of a specific model. But the model attributes should be set. This time you are passing CdetailView an empty model. You can write like this

```
$model = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->find(array('host_id'=>$id));
```

find method returns only one record.If you use `findAllByAttributes` then it returns an array of models but you need to show only one model so `find` method can be used.
So pass this model to CDatilView. like

```
 $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$model,'host_detail'=>$detail
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$model`, which is a new instance of `NimsoftHostsDetails`, into the `CDetailView` instead of passing `$host_detail`, the one created using info from the database. Also you only need one instance of `NimsoftHostDetails` so I suggest you go with `$model` as below:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $host_id=$id;
    $model = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_id'=>$id));
    $this->render('view',array('model'=>$model,));

}
```